# Using Browser Javascript on Server Side (in Rails 3)

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, dom, ruby-on-rails-3

There is a great bookmarklet script that takes a HTML document and, using javascript,  strips out the main article content (like Instapaper, but better).

***I want to know the most efficient way to use this same javascript script on the server side with Rails 3.***

Is it even possible? The ideal would be to be able to request a URL from the server (in Rails) and then parse the response using the javascript, and return the processed text (and then persist it to a db).

I was thinking of just adapting the script in Ruby, but this seems silly, especially since jQuery and javascript itself have a bunch of built-in functions for parsing a DOM. On the other hand, the script uses DOM constructions from the browser, so it might require a server-side browser?

Any suggestions?

Comment: what is the great bookmarklet?

Comment: Readability by Arc 90: (code) http://code.google.com/p/arc90labs-readability/ and (bookmark) http://lab.arc90.com/experiments/readability/

Comment: Nice script thanks for the info.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We actually do this very thing in one of our webapps. If you want to implement this functionality server-side in your Ruby on Rails application, your best bet is to use a Ruby HTML/XML parsing library, such as [Nokogiri](http://nokogiri.org/).

I wrote an article specifically explaining how to strip out the important information from a linked webpage, like Instapaper does, using Ruby + Nokogiri.

[Create a Printable Format for Any Webpage with Ruby and Nokogiri](http://www.alfajango.com/blog/create-a-printable-format-for-any-webpage-with-ruby-and-nokogiri/)

Comment: Awesome. This makes total sense. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe run the script in something like [Rhino Shell](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Rhino_Shell) and capture the output?

Answer (score 0):

[Node.js](http://nodejs.org/) comes to mind when speaking about server-side Javascript.

I think the Javascript stuff of readability could also be translated into Ruby but this would probably require some serious amount of work.